# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para actualizar un fichero con datos guardados en un boton?

Tags: php, javascript, html

[image: hacer para]

Tengo estos tres botones en mi página ... el primero selecciona un fichero, y al pulsar "Consultar" lo muestra en pantalla..., el segundo botón tiene la función de actualizar ese fichero en una tabla. El problema es que no logro hacer que se guarde el nombre de dicho fichero para utilizarlo en ese segundo botón.
Trabajo con `html`, `php` y `Js`. y las partes del programa son :

```html
function comprueba()
 {      
 var file11 = $("#file1").val();
            alert(file11);
   $("#formulario1").submit();

 }

 function actualizo()   {

        var file11 = $("#file11").val();
   $.ajax({
            url: 'actualizar_lineas.php',
            type: 'POST',
   data: {file11:file11},
            cache: false,
            async: true,
    success: function (data) {
   if(data!="")
                    alert(data);
                else
     alert(data);
                    alert('Actualizacion completada');
    }
            });
   }
```

En esta parte tengo las dos funciones la cual "comprueba"es la que hace la presentación, y "actualizo".. pues eso ... actualiza....

```html
<div style="text-aign: center">
    <input type="button" id="consultar" name="consultar" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:26px;" value=" Consultar "  onclick="comprueba11();"> 
    <input type="button" id="mostrar" name="mostrar"  class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:26px;"  onclick="actualizo();"  value=" Actualizar registros? " > 
 <input type="text" id="resul" name="resul"   style="margin-top:26px;" > 
</div>
```

Y esta es a parte del HTML.
Si pongo la opción de actualizar las lineas cuando pasan la primera vez funciona de maravilla, pero con ese segundo botón no llega a pasar el nombre del fichero.

¿Cómo podría hacer para solventar este problema?.

Comment: Hola, yo lo que haría sería mostrar el botón de Actualizar registros hasta que ya leíste todos los ficheros (guarda en una ruta el archivo excel para usarlo después al dar click en Actualizar registros)

Comment: perdona .. no capto la idea que me das,.. me lo explicas..??..

Comment: Claro, desde un inicio te propongo esconder el botón que se llama Actualizar registros. Cuando mandes tu excel a leer, dentro de tu código php, imprime este botón de actualizar registros para que al darle click, agarre el excel de nuevo y haga el proceso que necesites

Comment: perdona, he intentado hacerlo pero no lo consigo ..me podrías poner un ejemplo   para ver como se podría hacer.. soy algo nuevo y se me escapa... gracias por adelantado